# Passing a File to another maching with a same JAR file

Tags: java, jar

Here is my problem.

My package setup is:

```
-src
---- foo
-------- code.java    
---- foo.data
-------- files I need to access
```

Currently I have a jar that contains all of the above files I need to access. I will be running this code on my machine and send File objects initialized on my machine to another machine with the same jar running.

My question is how can I obtain a relative path to the data file so when I send the File objects to the other machine they know to look in the jar?

I need to access the data file so I can perform methods on it. Therefore I need to create a new File(relative/path/to/jar/data/files) with it and then I will be passing the File objects to another computer to compute.

Currently I have been able to use getClass().getResource("data/" + "filename").getPath() this gives me a path like file:/pathtojar!/pathtofileinjar/ which I think will be able to find the jar in the other machine but I am getting null pointer when trying to use the item in the jar.  Are files in jar able to be used or is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not send the relative path of the file in the jar, instead of the File?
The other program can then use that path and read the data from the jar.

Could you try with the absolute path, like so:

```
package resourcetest;

import java.net.URL;

public class ResourceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ResourceTest().test();
    }

    private void test() {
        URL res = this.getClass().getResource("/data/data.txt");
        System.out.println(res);
    }

}
```

Here my data file that i want to access is data/data.txt

src\resourcetest\ResourceTest.class (this class runs and tries to access data/Data.txt
  src\data\Data.txt

Comment: Sorry I should have made it a little more clear, I actually just tried that (last paragraph). The problem is it finds the file I want via the jar but when I try to use it I get null pointer problems.  Do you think I need to copy the file from the jar to the WD or something before I try to use it?